# Google maps transform in js

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dictionary, transform

I have some psd, where map looks like this:

[image: Map]

Is it possible to transform maps in this way?

edit: Sorry. I have not described issue fully. i need not styling (its really simple by constructor). i need **GEOMETRIC TRANSFORM** (scaling is getting less from equator to north)

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout here [Styling Google Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling)

If you scroll down to the page you will find a section "Google Maps APIs Styling Wizard". Styling wizard allows to create custom styles

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry: I have not described issue fully. i need not styling (its really simple by constructor). i need **GEOMETRIC TRANSFORM** (scaling is getting less from equator to north)